# JQuery form submit not sending post

Tags: jquery, forms

I am having trouble submitting a form with JQuery. The form submits correctly when the submit button is pressed, but when I try to use:

```
$('#somebutton').click(function(){
  $('form#myForm').submit();
});
```

I've additionally tried calling form submit from the Chrome console.

The form is not submitted correctly - from looking at the chrome inspector, it seems that the post message is never sent. The page is still reloaded, but seemingly without the changes that would be from the post data being sent.

Here's the form:

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input id="firstOption" type="radio" name="radioSelection" value="1" />
  <input id="secondOption" type="radio" name="radioSelection" value="2" />
  <input type="button" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" title="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am using JQuery v1.7.1.

Comment: Page reloads because the Action is reffering to self.

Comment: Seems like your missing the action in the form.

Comment: @M1K1O The page should be reloading - with slightly different content. It's not reloading with different content.

Comment: Are you sure, that PHP side is ok? Maybe there is the Problem hidden.

Comment: It seems to function correctly when the submit button is clicked manually - so I think things are OK over there.

Comment: Firstly, you're using radio buttons incorrectly, they should have the same name if they're different options of the same category. But also keep in mind that by pressing the submit button, the submitButton name/value pair is also passed along with the form data, which is different to if you submit it programatically. Otherwise everything should work.

Comment: Thanks sahbeewah - the naming was actually a typo when I cleaned up names for the post. I've fixed the question. I will take a look and see if I can submit the submit button as well.

Comment: @sahbeewah That seemed to be the problem - the backend was expecting a specific name/value pair in the submit buttons! Would you mind writing that up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you press the submit button, the submitButton name/value pair is also passed along with the form data, which is different to if you submit it programatically. This may cause the back-end to think that the POST was not submitted properly (depending on the implementation).

Comment: Just for other Google users: I was using `if(isset($_POST["send"]))` which caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have not defined the action page:

```
<form action="your_page.html" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - but that didn't seem to fix things. I was also under the impression it was OK to leave the action blank to point to the current page?

Comment: Yes, why is everyone upvoting this? This is wrong. The action attribute is optional and leaving it blank is perfectly legal and means you're submitting to the current url.

Comment: I am calling it inside of an onclick handler, and have additionally tried calling it from the Chrome console - neither of them work.

Answer (score 0):

here's your html:

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input id="firstOption" type="radio" name="firstOption" value="1" />
  <input id="secondOption" type="radio" name="secondOption" value="2" />
  <input type="button" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" title="Submit" />
</form>
```

And here's your jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(); 
  });
</script>
```

Cheers..!!

Comment: I believe you wanted to post the form once the page loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I actually wanted it reloaded on a button click. I've updated the question, I apologize for the confusion

Comment: Ok, you keep using $('form#myForm').submit(); I believe the appropriate selector is **'#myForm'** not **'form#myForm'**. It's just a thought cos I don't see any errors in your code.